# how to connect to a secure MQTT broker, with ESP12 using AT-COMMANDS?

Tags: mqtt, esp8266, at-command, messagebroker

I'm using an STM32 as the main microcontroller and ESP8266-12F as the Wi-Fi module. These 2 are connected to each other via serial port and communicate with each other by AT-COMMANDs. To program the STM32, I'm using Keil IDE and I'm not changing the firmware of the ESP8266 at all.

I have a secure MQTT with a CA.CRT file to which I want to connect.

1- What steps should I take to establish a connection between MQTT broker and ESP8266?

2- How should I add CA.CRT file to ESP8266?

3- What are the AT-COMMANDs which I need to use?

4- Can you provide a pseudo code to clarify the answer?

Comment: What have you already tried and how didn't it work?

Comment: Also have you been able to connect to none TLS broker?

Comment: ESP AT Command set does not support SSL. Only the ESP8266 Arduino Core support SSL. [Here](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/04/a-better-way-to-use-esp-01-as-wifi-shield/) is how I do it with STM32 and using an ESP-01 as WiFi shield.

Comment: In other projects, I have used the ESP module for connecting to the HTTP servers and it worked fine with no problem. However, in this project, I'm stuck at the first step. I cannot add the CA.CRT so as far as I know, I cannot access my SSL server.

Comment: @hcheung I reviewed the article that you mentioned and it clarified many things. Thanks. 
In that article, the writer mentioned that there is no way to use ESP as a wifi shield to connect to an SSL server. Is it true? Am I forced to write a firmware for ESP too?

Comment: is it possible to use AT+MQTTUSERCFG for connecting to the TLS broker?

Comment: Sorry for misleading you. I just found out that ESP AT command for TCP connection `AT+CIPSTART="TCP","url ", 8000 ` can be changed to support SSL like `AT+CIPSTART="SSL","url",443`, you might want to take a look at the [ESP8266 AT Command Set](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf). Personally I have not try yet.

Comment: @hcheung thanks for your help. I think I may find my answer in that document. I'm reading it and it looks promising. actually [ESP SSL user manual](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/5a-esp8266_sdk_ssl_user_manual_en.pdf)  can be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

After reading @hcheung comment and his proposed document, I found out that theoretically, I can solve this problem by the method mentioned on the 44th page of [ESP8266 AT Command Set](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf) and [ESP SSL user manual](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/5a-esp8266_sdk_ssl_user_manual_en.pdf).
In the coming week, I will check this and update this answer.